# Uploading a file as a stream of bytes with React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, reactjs-flux

I have a file that should be saved in the database through a java spring boot API.

ReactJS Front-end code:

```
  getContractBase64( vendor, value, index ) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL( value );
    const scope = this;
    reader.onload = function load () {
      vendor.contracts[index] = reader.result;
    };
    reader.onloadend = function loadend() {
      scope.setState( { vendor } );
    };
    this.setState( { vendor } );
  }
```

I am then sending the vendor entity to the REST endpoint.

Java Spring boot Back-End Code entity:

```
private byte[] document;
```

The controller:

```
@ApiOperation("Update a vendor")
@ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = SwaggerDescriptions.RESPONSE_CODE_200),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = SwaggerDescriptions.RESPONSE_CODE_400),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = SwaggerDescriptions.RESPONSE_CODE_403) })
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public VendorEntity update(@RequestBody @Valid VendorEntity entity) throws Exception {
    return vendorService.update(entity);
}
```

When an attempt is made to upload a file, it throws following error.

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Can not construct instance of com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABg.......)

Request Header:
    contracts{
    0:"data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCQdr5P...
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: check the update @RavindraRanwala

Comment: What is the content type your back end expects? I guess it should be multipart-related data?

Comment: a stream of bytes private byte[] document; @RavindraRanwala

Comment: What part of 'Can not construct instance of com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABg.......)
' don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP what do you suggest?